# How to execute code from a Vue project using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, babeljs

I just started to work on an existing [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) project and I would like to run some of its components from nodejs, e.g. if I want to test some component separately without compiling and deploying the complete application to a browser.

As far as I have understood, Vue uses [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile its projects, and Babel allows using `@` in the paths of import statements.
On the other hand, nodejs cannot resolve these paths: when I run a script that imports a module from the Vue application, I get the error:

```
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@/package' imported from myfile.js
```

So, I wanted to ask if there is a way to have nodejs resolve `@`-paths and load code from a Vue package.
I hope I have formulated the problem correctly, since I am a beginner with Vue and Javascript in general.

Comment: If it's ESModule imports (`import` you can write a loader and pass it as `--loader` when running Node.js. If It's commonjs (`require`) you can use a require hook instead. I would recommend reading https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html on a bit of how to access Vue code from server contexts since I think your problem can be bypassed rather than requiring a hook/loader.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: It's an ESModule `import` and the original code in turn imports other modules. All imports are ESModule imports but they contain `@`, i.e. they do not specify a path on the filesystem. I think Vue uses this `@` in a special way to resolve paths.